# Cocoa ivar losing value between init and drawRect

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsview

I am not a complete n00b here, but I feel like I must be missing something essential. I'm passing a variable into a new class instance via the class's init method:

```
@synthesize side;

- (id)initWithSide:(NSString *)aSide frame:(NSRect)frameRect
{
    if (self = [super initWithFrame:(NSRect)frameRect]) {
        self.side = aSide;
    }
    NSLog(@"Side is %@", self.side);
    return self;
}
```

The output from NSLog() does show the correct value here. Now, the drawRect: method that is then triggered to draw the view, has a similar call:

```
- (void)drawRect:(NSRect)rect
{
    NSLog(@"Side is %@", self.side);
```

And this time the NSLog() reports Side as nil! Stepping through it with the debugger, I see the value for side gets set, then it goes into the registers (all those hex codes that I don't understand), then when it jumps out again into the drawRect: method, the value is simply nil.

If anyone can shed light on this I'd appreciate it!

Cheers,
Aaron

Comment: Post more code, specifically, what does the protocol declaration look like? And are you synthesizing it, or are you supplying your own implementation of the setter?

Comment: @jer You mean the `@interface` declaration?

Comment: No, I meant the property. Starts off `@property ...`

Comment: Here it is: @property (readwrite, assign) NSString * side;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to go ahead and guess the most common cause for this kind of bug: You're dealing with two different objects. You're initializing the view in your code *and* you also have an instance in a nib. The two instances are completely separate objects, so when the view that is visible performs its drawRect:, it doesn't see the other one's instance variable.

The problem with your property that other people are pointing out is also definitely true, but I suspect this bug is actually hiding that one.

Comment: I am using IB to instantiate the objects that are represented here. Is it therefore necessary to chuck (sorry, pun intended) that and do my view in code instead? I'm pretty sure this has worked in other circumstances...

Comment: I agree with the diagnostic. Use NSLog("%p", self) in both methods to confirm the problem.

Comment: Confirmed! They are different objects. Umm... now what?

Comment: @Aaron Vegh: In awakeFromNib or similar, set the Interface Builder view's size property. Chuck the one you've created in code. It'll probably be simpler.

Answer (score 2):

This is usually the way to write a property for NSString*.
assign is used for primitive types (it doesn't increment the retain count for an object), and either retain or copy for Objects.

```
 @property (readwrite, copy) NSString * side
```

Comment: As a corollary to the above; Generally you copy things when you don't want them potentially changing their value out from underneath you, such is the case almost always with strings and urls.

Comment: Fair enough. Made the change, but the value still isn't sticking around... :-(